# syntax for string array in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

This is my working jsp code which gets attributes from from my servlet.

```
<%
int[]  arr1= (int[]) session.getAttribute("population");
String[]  arr2 = (String[]) session.getAttribute("countrycode");
%>
```

The code below shows the correct output:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var a="<%=arr1[0]%>"; 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
</script>
```

However, the code below does not show the correct output:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var a="<%=arr2[0]%>"; 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
}
</script>
```

arr1 and arr2 are populated from the database, with arr1 storing integers and arr2 storing varchar2(SQL DEVELOPER TYPE) values. arr1[0] has the value 75 and arr2[0] has the value US.

Comment: please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: anyone who know about jsp expression . ??

Comment: show us your arr2 values.

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh Thanks for your reply .

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh arr2 values are string that contains country code like US, IN, CN .... while arr1 contains number like 23, 75 , 63 .  but when i execute second code it shows var a="CN";   Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh maybe it is taking CN as a variable not string .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem in storing String into database.
Click on the table you are using in database. make sure that string does not end after new Line. Meaning CURSOR should end after ending string .
for example if you want to store string as CN in SQL developer .
it should like this
CN|
it should not like this
CN
|

where | shows cursor .